# How to Output Mapper Key as Text to the Reducer in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to convert a String into a Text object and output the value to the Reducer as MapOutputKey. However, in the reducer, the key looks like a black space with value(not the MapOutputValue) as a memory location.
However, if i hardcode a String into the text object and send it out, I am able to see the proper values in the Reducer.
EDIT:- Now this is very strange AND interesting. The same program works fine for a smaller dataset,i.e, The text key sent from the mapper is received in the reducer. But if i use the original dataset, the text key sent from map does not reflect in the reducer.
I don'n know, there is something about Hadoop that i am not aware of.
Here is the entire source code:-

```
 public class InvertedIndex {
    public InvertedIndex(){}
    public static class InvertedMap extends Mapper<IntWritable,Text,Text,DocAttributes> {
        Integer docNum;
        String word;
        Integer docFrequency;
        Integer termFrequency;
        private Text key = new Text();
        @Override
        public void map(IntWritable mapIn,Text mapValIn,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
            try{
                String line = mapValIn.toString();
                String[] words = line.trim().split("\\s");
                List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
                String k;
                for(int i=0; i<wordList.size();i++){
                   k = wordList.get(i);
                    //Text key = new Text(k);
                  //  DocAttributes da = new DocAttributes();
                    key.set(k);
                    int sum=1;
                    for(int j=i;j<wordList.size();j++){

                        if(wordList.get(i).matches(wordList.get(j)) && j>i){
                            sum++;
                            docNum = mapIn.get();
                            docFrequency = sum;
                            word = wordList.get(i);
                            termFrequency = sum;
                            wordList.remove(j);
                        }


                        else{
                            docNum = mapIn.get();
                            docFrequency = sum;
                            word = wordList.get(i);
                            termFrequency = sum;
                        }

                    }
                    if(i == words.length-1){
                        docNum = mapIn.get();
                        docFrequency = sum;
                        word = wordList.get(i);
                        termFrequency = sum;
                    }
                    context.write(key, new DocAttributes(docNum,word,docFrequency,termFrequency));
                }
            }
            catch(NullPointerException ne){
                ne.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    public static class InvertedReduce extends Reducer<Text,DocAttributes,LongWritable,DocAttributes>{
       @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<DocAttributes> value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
            Iterator<DocAttributes> iterator = value.iterator();
            DocAttributes doc = new DocAttributes();
            List<DocAttributes> list = new ArrayList<DocAttributes>();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                list.add(new DocAttributes(iterator.next()));
            }
            Integer docFrequency = 0;
            for(DocAttributes d : list){
                docFrequency += d.getDocFrequency();
                doc.setDocNum(d.getDocNum());
                doc.setWord(d.getWord());
                doc.setDocFrequency(docFrequency);
                doc.setTermFrequency(d.getTermFrequency());
           }

           context.write(new LongWritable(), doc);

       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);

        job.setMapperClass(InvertedMap.class);
        // job.setCombinerClass(InvertedCombine.class);
        job.setReducerClass(InvertedReduce.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(DocAttributes.class);

        job.setJarByClass(InvertedIndex.class);

        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));

        job.setInputFormatClass(DocInput.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.submit();
        job.waitForCompletion(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: Link to test  dataset-> <https://app.box.com/s/kusmmqnbp8l1na86vbetpdr8yk7cqu43>
Link to Original daaset->
<https://app.box.com/s/unbpgelp0azxrxg4pc7wwpf8j9yfgu3o>

Comment: Link is not opening.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying ArrayList 'wordList' on iteration using for each loop.Can you try using Iterator loop to remove elements (Iterator.remove()) on iteration.

Comment: I need to have a nested loop to perform validation. Also i dont think that would make any difference because if I change the MapKeyOutput value to Intwritable/Logwritable, It will begin to work fine. Also if I construct the Text object with hardcoded String( new Text("some_string")), it works fine.

Comment: Can you refer to the solution given in this link to remove item from list to see if it's working (for this statement - wordList.remove(j)) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing

Comment: try debugging by just emitting key-value pairs without those logic and see if it's properly coming in reducer.